# How can I put a delay on a submenu everytime the parent menu is hovered? (Front-end)

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I am trying to put a delay effect on my submenu.

```
  <ul id="main-menu">
       <li class="firstLevel hasSubmenu"><a href="/inmotus/" class="firstLevel">    
  <nav class="submenu">                 
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><font><font class="">About</font></font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font><font class="">Sample</font></font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font><font>Inmotus misse &amp; Vision</font></font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font><font class="">Voluptatem</font></font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font><font class="">Ratione</font></font></a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
  <ul>
```

**Problem:** How can i apply a delay on my **.submenu** class every time **.hasSubmenu** class is hovered?

Please help me...

Comment: A delay for what type of action? Please post the javascript code too.

Comment: where is your `li` getting closed for your main menu.

Comment: with what you are making animation of menu? through 3rd party tool or using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.submenu').hide();
$( '.hasSubmenu' ).hover( function() {
_this = $(this).parents().find('.submenu');
setTimeout(function() { 
_this.fadeIn(); }, 500);
}, function() {
_this.fadeOut();
});
});
```

Try something like this. (FIXED)

http://jsfiddle.net/swp64ydv/1/

Comment: the this inside a setTimeout is different. You need to pass the context from function(){_this = this;setTimout({
$(_this).children('.submenu').fadeIn();
}, 500);}

Comment: Hi Voltlight, thanks for your answer. It's correct :)

Comment: Great, you're welcome - You should probably nest the submenus within the .hasMenu properly, by the way, the HTML isn't correct

Answer (score 1):

If your code is based on javascript, This link would be much helpful.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts to determine the user's intent... like a crystal ball, only with mouse movement! It is similar to jQuery's hover method. However, instead of calling the handlerIn function immediately, hoverIntent waits until the user's mouse slows down enough before making the call.

It has a configuration to change the delay on hover, have a look at is it suit to you.

Answer (score 1):

You code is not properly as i understand from your code, below is a solution. I hope it will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li.firstLevel').click(function(){
    $('ul ul').slideToggle();
    });
})
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/4qnomg3c/)***

Change the value

```
$('ul ul').slideToggle(600);
```

then you manage the delay timing.

Comment: Thanks for the response Maddy :)

Comment: It's all my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you expect after delay but assuming you want it to appear

```
$('.hasSubmenu').mouseenter(function()
{
setTimeout(function(){handleMouseAction(true);},500)
}).mouseleave(function()
{
setTimeout(function(){handleMouseAction(false);},500)
});

function handleMouseAction(actionFLag)
{
if(actionFlag)
{
$('submenu').show();
}
else
{
$('submenu').hide();
}
}
```